# Integrating UIViewController with Storyboard into SwiftUI Project: A Gap at the Top after Transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swiftui

I have a sample **SwiftUI** project to find out whether or not I can transition from SwiftUI `View` to **UIKit** `UIViewController`.  And I can.

The following is my `UIViewController`.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    }
}

struct HomeViewControllerRepresentation: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<HomeViewControllerRepresentation>) -> HomeViewController {
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: HomeViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<HomeViewControllerRepresentation>) {

    }
}
```

And I have SwiftUI `View` as follows.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: HomeViewControllerRepresentation()) {
                    Text("Tap me")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If I tap the link, I will be forwarded to the `ViewVontroller`.  That's good except that I have a big gap at the top.  Where does it come from and how can I get rid of it?  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you might have two Navigation's.  One form the Storyboard and the one in SwiftUI, which would cause something like this.

Comment: @MwcsMac My storyboard doesn't contain the navigation controller.  And my view controller is not connected to the navigation controller.

Comment: I had a similar problem once and it was because I had a child `ViewController` view on the parent that was constrained to the top of parent view more than the safe area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is empty large header area of `NavigationView`, so just hide it

```
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: HomeViewControllerRepresentation()) {
                Text("Tap me")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
```